# cannot import name patterns - django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and, Python Tools for VS 2013 to get started with a Django website.

**It gives the following error,**

[image]

**Full traceback**

```
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\my_username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DjangoWebProject
1\DjangoWebProject1\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 58, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 97, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 108, in run
    self.inner_run(None, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374,
 in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361,
 in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81,
in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in c
heck_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in c
heck_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in ur
l_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in ur
lconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\users\my_username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DjangoWebProject
1\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: As a start, try running this not in debug mode, and attach the full traceback to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patterns` was removed in Django 1.10.  Instead, use a regular list:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/) for more info.

Comment: File "c:\users\my_usrname\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name views
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Please start a new question. Attach your traceback properly. If this solved the problem, accept the answer.

Comment: I have applied your solution and that didn't work. Leting you know that was the sole purpose of those two comments

Comment: `cannot import name views` means it can't import a module (Python file) called views.py . That's a different problem. Stack overflow is not a debugger.