# cannot import name views - django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and, Python Tools for VS 2013 to get started with a Django website.

> Related question:
>   [cannot import name patterns - django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711286/cannot-import-name-patterns-django/42767618?noredirect=1#comment72655187_42767618)

I have fixed this and now I am getting the following error,

[image]

**Full traceback,**

```
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my_username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 58, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 97, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 108, in run
    self.inner_run(None, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\my_username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name views
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**How can I fix this?**

---

[image]

---

**Relevant Source Code**

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Comment: What steps have you done to get started? What files do you have in the project directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711286/cannot-import-name-patterns-django/42767618?noredirect=1#comment72655187_42767618

Comment: @PenguinBrian, screenshot added.

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name views` — you simply don't have `views.py` file on the same level as `urls.py`.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov, okay. I moved `views.py` to the `DjangoWebProject1`. Now,  the previous problem comes back again.

Comment: I would suggest - if you haven't already done so - going through the Django tutorial - and come back to this problem afterwards and see if that helps: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/ (This is for Django 1.10)

Answer (score 1):

```
   from django.conf.urls import url

   from app import views
   #name of your app
   urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
   url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
   url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
   url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', 
   views.article_detail),
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `from app import views`

I am working under the assumption that your `urls.py` is the one that is found in the `DjangoWebProject1` directory/package

Answer (score 0):

```
Django version 2.2, venv - with pycharm community version
```

hey i just create new separate  urls.py in app directory

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dbsave),





"""


 main urls.py 


"""  

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('user_reg.urls')),

]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As explanations are an important part of answers on this platform, please explain your code and how it solves the problem in the question. Our guide [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might be helpful for you. Thanks!